# how to write an Axios query where I don't know a parent value?

Tags: firebase, axios

I have a simple firebase DB which looks like

```
someNode: {
 pushId-A: {param1: 'some string'},
 pushId-B: {param1: 'some other string')
}
```

<strike>Using Axios GET, is there a way to query someNode for the value of param1 where I don't know the value of the pushId?</strike>

I want it to return the pushId of the node that contains "param1: 'some string'.

[EDIT}

I understand now that this is not an Axios question, but rather a Firebase question.

I've read the firebase docs  here:
[Filtering Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data)

But when I send the get request with any paramaters other than the auth token, I get back a 400 code. Which tells me it is incorrectly syntaxed.

here is the last part of the DB url

```
a8/data/houses/-L4OiszP7IOzkfh1f1NY/houseName
```

where houseName = "Aubergine"

Trying to filter for houseName I am passing:

```
axios.get('/houses.json/' + '?orderBy="houseName"&startAt="A"' + '&auth=' + token)
```

I'm keeping the params separate so I can more easily read and change them. Concatenating the strings has no effect.

No matter what combination of params I pass I get the 400 error code. If I leave them off, then the data comes through as expected.

What am I doing wrong????